# Knockout Paging in MVC with Web API

Tags: asp.net-mvc, knockout.js, asp.net-web-api

I can't get this code to page.  The table's page size is always the same -  the number of items returned from the `Web API` call.  The parameter that is passed-in is ignored (3).  Also, the back and forward button elements don't have icons (*icon-step-backward* and *icon-step-forward*), but this is secondary to the page size.

**HTML**

```
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th data-column="LastName">Last Name</th>
            <th data-column="FirstName">First Name</th>
            <th data-column="EnrollmentDate">Enrollment Date</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: students">
        <tr>
            <td data-bind="text: LastName" />
            <td data-bind="text: FirstName" />
            <td data-bind="text: EnrollmentDate" />
        </tr>
    </tbody>

    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Number of items per page:
                <select id="pageSizeSelector" data-bind="value: pageSize">
                    <option value="1">1</option>
                    <option value="2">2</option>
                    <option value="3">3</option>
                    <option value="4">4</option>
                    <option value="5">5</option>
                    <option value="6">6</option>
                    <option value="7">7</option>
                    <option value="8">8</option>
                    <option value="9">9</option>
                    <option value="10">10</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td colspan="3">
                <button data-bind="click: previousPage" class="btn"><i class="icon-step-backward"></i></button>
                Page<label data-bind="text: currentPageIndex() + 1" class="badge"></label>
                <button data-bind="click: nextPage" class="btn"><i class="icon-step-forward"></i></button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

**KNOCKOUT and JQUERY**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var viewModel = function () {
        self = this;
        self.currentPage = ko.observable();
        self.pageSize = ko.observable(3);
        self.currentPageIndex = ko.observable(0);
        self.students = ko.observableArray();
        self.currentPage = ko.computed(function () {
            var pagesize = parseInt(self.pageSize(), 3),
            startIndex = pagesize * self.currentPageIndex(),
            endIndex = startIndex + pagesize;
            return self.students.slice(startIndex, endIndex);
        });

        self.nextPage = function () {
            if (((self.currentPageIndex() + 1) * self.pageSize()) < self.students().length) {
                self.currentPageIndex(self.currentPageIndex() + 1);
            }
            else {
                self.currentPageIndex(0);
            }
        }
        self.previousPage = function () {
            if (self.currentPageIndex() > 0) {
                self.currentPageIndex(self.currentPageIndex() - 1);
            }
            else {
                self.currentPageIndex((Math.ceil(self.students().length / self.pageSize())) - 1);
            }
        }
    }

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://localhost:12769/api/student",
            type: "GET"
        }).done(function (data) {
            var vm = new viewModel();
            vm.students(data);
            ko.applyBindings(vm);
        }).error(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(jqXHR.responseText || textStatus);
        });
    });

</script>
```

**JSON Returned From Web API**

```
[{"$id":"1","ID":1,"LastName":"Alexander","FirstMidName":"Carson","EnrollmentDate":"2005-09-01T00:00:00","Enrollments":[{"$id":"2","EnrollmentID":1,"CourseID":1050,"StudentID":1,"Grade":0,"Course":{"$id":"3","CourseID":1050,"Title":"Chemistry","Credits":3},"Student":{"$ref":"1"}},{"$id":"4","EnrollmentID":2,"CourseID":4022,"StudentID":1,"Grade":2,"Course":{"$id":"5","CourseID":4022,"Title":"Microeconomics","Credits":3},"Student":{"$ref":"1"}},{"$id":"6","EnrollmentID":3,"CourseID":4041,"StudentID":1,"Grade":1,"Course":{"$id":"7","CourseID":4041,"Title":"Macroeconomics","Credits":3},"Student":{"$ref":"1"}}]},{"$id":"8","ID":2,"LastName":"Alonso","FirstMidName":"Meredith","EnrollmentDate":"2002-09-01T00:00:00","Enrollments":[{"$id":"9","EnrollmentID":4,"CourseID":1045,"StudentID":2,"Grade":1,"Course":{"$id":"10","CourseID":1045,"Title":"Calculus","Credits":4},"Student":{"$ref":"8"}},{"$id":"11","EnrollmentID":5,"CourseID":3141,"StudentID":2,"Grade":4,"Course":{"$id":"12","CourseID":3141,"Title":"Trigonometry","Credits":4},"Student":{"$ref":"8"}},{"$id":"13","EnrollmentID":6,"CourseID":2021,"StudentID":2,"Grade":4,"Course":{"$id":"14","CourseID":2021,"Title":"Composition","Credits":3},"Student":{"$ref":"8"}}]},{"$id":"15","ID":3,"LastName":"Anand","FirstMidName":"Arturo","EnrollmentDate":"2003-09-01T00:00:00","Enrollments":[{"$id":"16","EnrollmentID":7,"CourseID":1050,"StudentID":3,"Grade":null,"Course":{"$ref":"3"},"Student":{"$ref":"15"}}]},{"$id":"17","ID":4,"LastName":"Barzdukas","FirstMidName":"Gytis","EnrollmentDate":"2002-09-01T00:00:00","Enrollments":[{"$id":"18","EnrollmentID":8,"CourseID":1050,"StudentID":4,"Grade":null,"Course":{"$ref":"3"},"Student":{"$ref":"17"}},{"$id":"19","EnrollmentID":9,"CourseID":4022,"StudentID":4,"Grade":4,"Course":{"$ref":"5"},"Student":{"$ref":"17"}}]},{"$id":"20","ID":5,"LastName":"Li","FirstMidName":"Yan","EnrollmentDate":"2002-09-01T00:00:00","Enrollments":[{"$id":"21","EnrollmentID":10,"CourseID":4041,"StudentID":5,"Grade":2,"Course":{"$ref":"7"},"Student":{"$ref":"20"}}]},{"$id":"22","ID":6,"LastName":"Justice","FirstMidName":"Peggy","EnrollmentDate":"2001-09-01T00:00:00","Enrollments":[{"$id":"23","EnrollmentID":11,"CourseID":1045,"StudentID":6,"Grade":null,"Course":{"$ref":"10"},"Student":{"$ref":"22"}}]},{"$id":"24","ID":7,"LastName":"Norman","FirstMidName":"Laura","EnrollmentDate":"2003-09-01T00:00:00","Enrollments":[{"$id":"25","EnrollmentID":12,"CourseID":3141,"StudentID":7,"Grade":0,"Course":{"$ref":"12"},"Student":{"$ref":"24"}}]},{"$id":"26","ID":8,"LastName":"Olivetto","FirstMidName":"Nino","EnrollmentDate":"2005-09-01T00:00:00","Enrollments":[]}]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One reason it might not be working for you, is that you are using `parseInt` with a radix of 3. So in your `currentPage` ko computed, the line `var pagesize = parseInt(self.pageSize(), 3)` is going to result in a `NaN`. See the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) for more info.

Here's a helpful paging extension for a KO observable array, and it will clean up your view model as well. See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UaD3R/3/) for a working example. In your case, your viewmodel would simply be

```
var viewmodel = function(){
     var self = this;
     self.students = ko.observableArray().paged(3);
}
```

Your HTML would be this:

```
<table data-bind="foreach: students.pagedItems">
    <!-- normal data binding syntax here -->
</table>
```

And some pagination controls. These are using Bootstrap classes, but gives you an idea of how to use them:

```
<ul class="pagination">
    <li data-bind="css: { disabled: students.currentPageIndex() === 0 }"><a href="#" data-bind="click: students.previousPage">&laquo;</a></li>
</ul>
<ul class="pagination" data-bind="foreach: students.allPages">
    <li data-bind="css: { active: pageNumber === ($root.students.currentPageIndex() + 1) }">
        <a href="#" data-bind="text: pageNumber, click: function() { $root.students.moveToPage(pageNumber-1); }"></a>
    </li>
</ul>
<ul class="pagination">
    <li data-bind="css: { disabled: students.currentPageIndex() === students.maxPageIndex() }"><a href="#" data-bind="click: students.nextPage">&raquo;</a></li>
</ul>
<br />
<span data-bind="text: students.currentStatus"></span>
```

And here's the extension. I have a second option to pass a sorting function in, but it is completely optional.

```
ko.observableArray.fn.paged = function (perPage, sortComparator) {
            var items = this;

            items.currentPage = ko.observable();
            items.pageSize = ko.observable(perPage);
            items.currentPageIndex = ko.observable(0);

            items.currentItemPage = ko.computed(function () {
                var pagesize = parseInt(items.pageSize(), 10),
                    startIndex = pagesize * items.currentPageIndex(),
                    endIndex = startIndex + pagesize;
                return this().slice(startIndex, endIndex);
            }, items);

            items.pagedItems = ko.computed(function () {
                var size = parseInt(items.pageSize(), 10),
                    start = items.currentPageIndex() * size;

                if (typeof (sortComparator) === "function") {
                    var sorted = this().sort(sortComparator);
                    return sorted.slice(start, start + size);
                } else {
                    return this().slice(start, start + size);
                }


            }, items);

            items.maxPageIndex = ko.computed(function () {
                return Math.ceil(this().length / items.pageSize()) - 1;
            }, items);

            items.allPages = ko.computed(function () {
                var pages = [];
                for (var i = 0; i <= items.maxPageIndex() ; i++) {
                    pages.push({ pageNumber: (i + 1) });
                }
                return pages;
            }, items);

            items.currentStatus = ko.computed(function () {
                var pagesize = parseInt(items.pageSize(), 10),
                    start = pagesize * items.currentPageIndex(),
                    end = start + pagesize;

                if (items.currentPageIndex() === items.maxPageIndex()) end = this().length;

                return 'Showing ' + (start + 1) + ' to ' + end + ' of ' + this().length;
            }, items);

            items.nextPage = function () {
                if (((items.currentPageIndex() + 1) * items.pageSize()) < items().length) {
                    items.currentPageIndex(items.currentPageIndex() + 1);
                } else {
                    items.currentPageIndex(0);
                }
            };

            items.previousPage = function () {
                if (items.currentPageIndex() > 0) {
                    items.currentPageIndex(items.currentPageIndex() - 1);
                } else {
                    items.currentPageIndex((Math.ceil(items().length / items.pageSize())) - 1);
                }
            };

            items.moveToPage = function (index) {
                items.currentPageIndex(index);
            };

            return items;
        };
```

Comment: I not sure what a good Radix value will be.  Do I need to use parseInt?  I tried your extension and I get the correct number in the table but the paging doesn't work.  Is this because I have it in the <tfoot> and the data-bind is in the <tbody>?  Thanks

Comment: You would want to use a radix of 10, so `parseInt(pagesize, 10)`. If you used the code that I posted, it shouldn't matter if the paging stuff is in the `<tfoot>`. I usually don't use a `<tfoot>` though, so I can't say for sure.

Comment: Turned out I had an incorrect `this` reference in the `nextPage` and `previousPage` functions. Updated my answer, and posted a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rwisch45/UaD3R/2/)

Comment: @BigDaddy Did you see the fiddle I posted? Work for you?

Comment: Thanks, the fiddle works like charm and I can get your code to work in my project with the hard-coded data.  However, I can't get it to work using a ajax call, which I need.  I moved put the mapping.fromJS into the .done call back and no help.  Also I don't see where the Student class you created is used.

Comment: @BigDaddy I removed the Student class. Was using it for debugging until I realized my error with the `this`. Also, I was just using the mapping plugin because I'm used to it - you don't have to use that. Could you post some of the sample JSON returned by your api call so we can see the structure of it? Also, do you get error(s) in your web dev tools console in or around the call to your api?

Comment: Updated original post with JSON returned

Comment: @BigDaddy Are you using web developer tools? Any errors in the console window? Also, your JSON is using `FirstMidName` and your HTML is binding to `FirstName`

Comment: Nice catch, the problem was with FirstMidName.  I updated the KO foreach and It works great now, thanks.